# ASP.NET code blocks in server tags

Tags: asp.net

Can you not have code blocks in server tags?  For example, I wish to create custom id fields using code blocks. (I know there are other way to do this with repeaters, but in my particular situation I'd like to do things this way if its possible for irrelevant reasons.)

```
<% foreach(var reference in references) { %>
...
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID='lbUpdateEmail_<%=reference.ReferenceId%>' OnClick="lbUpdateEmail_Click" style="float:right;">Update Email</asp:LinkButton>
...
<% } %>
```

Comment: what is the reason behind generating ID in this manner? any specific example of why you would want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use <% %> inside server tags.

Although ASP.NET seems very dynamic in it's behavior, you have to remember that the pages are actually compiled to .NET classes.

In this case the LinkButton tag you are using indicates that you want your page class to contain an instance of LinkButton, and the ID gives you the name of the Property you will use to access this at design time (when you are editing your code.)

Let's say in your code behind you wanted to disable the link button? How would you refer to it if the ID was not yet determined?

Also, remember that the "ID" you set is not the the "id" that gets rendered in HTML - if that was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to add your link button at code behind programmatically instead :

```
foreach(var reference in references) 
{
    LinkButton newLinkButton = new LinkButton();
    newLinkButton.Text = "Update Email";
    newLinkButton.Click += new EventHandler(a_lbUpdateEmail_Click);
    myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(newLinkButton);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you turn on ASP 3.0 Classic Compatibility Mode you can do this; that said, I'd really recommend looking into another approach.